# How to remove the scrollbar on mobile devices?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I used a css code to remove the scrollbar and its working for desktop but it still shows the bar when I look from my smartphone.

The code I used:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want no scrollbars at all, then use `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:

```
<body scroll="no">
```

Comment: Please explaina why this can help.